# read operation with two interchanging processes and context switch

Tags: linux, hard-drive, process

P1 and P2 are both processes, different from each other.
this is a read operation done on the hard disk:

[image]

Given above is a diagram of a read instuction in Linux, Is it true that it's better to avoid using a context switch to better the overall preformance?

(a) true, because it avoids swapping in the TLB.

(b) true.

(c) wrong.

(d) wrong, it's impossible to avoid performing a context switch

Why is the answer simply (c)? I was thinking that the student can't be right because avoiding a context switch doesn't better overall preformance since context switching is used to better preformance.

I was thinking it should be (d) beause when we go from P1 to P2 we need a context switch to go from one process to another.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It seems one ought to choose (c) over (d) simply because (d) is untrue.

When P1 goes after a while into a read stage we're talking about IO, therefore the CPU is busy. It has to first process the IO request and get to that data, so while it's doing exactly that, the scheduler runs another process so that we don't lose time - this however has nothing to do with a context switch.

This is what I think. Does this seems logical?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to avoid one context switch (the switch from P2 to P1) by not scheduling P2 to run while waiting for the disk operation to complete. Presumably, if you did that then P1 would resume execution slightly sooner, with a warmer TLB.

You can't avoid all context switching because the system call involves a context switch (user to kernel) as does the resumption of P1 after the completion interrupt from the device. But you *could* avoid two switches of the user context (though only one of the switches affects P1's timing).

So, if your only measurement of performance is how fast P1 executes, then you could extract a tiny bit more by dedicating that CPU to P1 and not allowing any other processes to run. But we know that disk activity is slow compared to context switching, and the question is about *overall* performance, not about P1 alone. So it makes sense to schedule P2 to run during the wait, even though it will introduce a small delay in resuming P1 later.

Comment: What do you mean by a warmer TLB? (I know that the TLB is a sort of lookup table, so if P1 resumes it should look into the TLB to find the mapping of its memory)

Comment: This is very dependent on your particular hardware, but frequently, after a switch to a new process the TLB starts out empty. When the user process tries to access a location with no TLB entry (a "TLB miss"), there's a kernel trap, the kernel figures out the correct physical page for that address based on its address mappings for that specific user process and updates the TLB. This takes time. Since the TLB is basically a cache of address lookups, people speak of a "cold" or "warm" TLB like any other cache.